# Elasticsearch Function Scoring based on max score within array / nested

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

I have a field within my document, which stores an array of Integers.

**Java Class:**

```
public class Clazz {
    public List<Foo> foo;

    public static Foo {
         public Integer bar;
         public Integer baz;
    }
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
"properties" : {
    "foo" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bar" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "baz" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example documents:**

```
{
    id: 1
    foo: [
        { bar: 10 }, 
        { bar: 20 }
    ]
},

{
    id: 2
    foo: [
        { bar: 15 }
    ]
}
```

Now I'd like to do my scoring. The scoring function is given an `input` value: `10`.

And the scoring function basically is: *"The closer `foo.bar` is to `input`, the higher the score. And if `foo.bar` is lower than `input` the score is only half as good"*

**The query:**

```
"function_score" : {
    "functions" : [ {
        "script_score" : {
            "script" : "if(doc['foo.bar'].value >= input) { (input - doc['foo.bar'].value) * 1 } else { (doc['foo.bar'].value - input) * 2 }",
            "lang" : "groovy",
            "params" : {
                "input" : 10
            }
      }
} ],
"score_mode" : "max",
"boost_mode" : "replace"
```

}

**Expected result:**

`id 1` should be first, because there's a `foo.bar` that matches `input=10`.

**What happens:**

The scoring works perfectly, if the documents have only **a single** `foo.bar` value. If it's an array (like in document with `id 1`) Elasticsearch seems to take the last value within the array.

**What the query should do:**

Take the best score. That's why I used `score_mode: max`. But it seems, that this only respects the `functions` array within the `function_score`, and not (as I did expect) the possible scores within a function.

---

I read somewhere about using `doc['foo.bar'].values` (value**s** instead of value), but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Do you have an idea, how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this using groovy is as below i.e you can use the max method of list on values.

Example :

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "max_score=doc[\"foo.bar\"].values.max();if(max_score >= input) {return (max_score - input);} else { return (max_score - input) *2;}",
                  "lang": "groovy",
                  "params": {
                     "input": 10
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "max",
         "boost_mode": "replace"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: there is equivalent in `Painless`?